# Where to put 'monkeypatches' in Nuxt.js?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, monkeypatching

where can I put 'monkeypatches' and 'my extensions' to prototypes of basic javascript objects in Nuxt framework to have it's functionality accesible accros all files ?

for example:

```
String.prototype.capitalize = function () {

    return this.replace(/\w\S*/g, function(txt){return txt.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + txt.substr(1).toLowerCase();});
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hello you can create a `~/plugins/my-extensions.js` file with your code sample. This code will be run once (server-side and client-side as well) and will make available your extensions methods everywhere.

Do not forget to register your plugin in `nuxt.config.js`:

```js
export default {
  plugins: ['~/plugins/my-extensions.js']
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This is prototype pollution and a bad practice. There are better ways to share common function:

1. Put them in a utility file (e.g. under `utils/helpers.js` and import them from there

```js
  export const capitalize = s => s.replace(/\w\S*/g, 
    txt => txt.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + txt.substr(1).toLowerCase()
  )
```

2. Use a Nuxt plugin to `inject` the helper function, so it's available in all components (though this might be a bit overkill here). See [here](https://nuxtjs.org/guides/directory-structure/plugins#inject-in-root--context)

I highly suggest to avoid prototype pollution.